# Getting multiple data items in an element with linq to xml

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

Getting multiple data items in an element with linq to xml

I have an xml file like this

```
<TopLevel>
  <Inside>
    Jibba
  </Inside>
  <Inside>
    Jabba
  </Inside>
</TopLevel>
```

I was given said xml and and want to get all the elements. Here is the code I have.

```
    var q = from c in loaded.Descendants("TopLevel")
            select (XElement)c.Element("Inside");
```

I tried c.Elements but that did not work. What do I need to do to get all of the internal elements? This code just gets the first "Inside" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you `"Jibba"` and `"Jabba"`; you'll need `using` directives for both `System.Linq` and `System.Xml.Linq`:

```
    var q = from c in loaded.Descendants("TopLevel").Elements("Inside")
            select c.Value;
```

or (less specific, but still works):

```
    var q = from c in loaded.Descendants("TopLevel").Elements()
            select c.Value;
```

or if you want to do something more with the elements, `SelectMany`:

```
    var q = from c in loaded.Descendants("TopLevel")
            from i in c.Elements("Inside")
            select i.Value;
```

(if you want the element, not the string, then just `select c;` or `select i;` - remove the `.Value`)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to take this a step further and wasn't real clear as to how to do it.  Thanks for the jump off point.  Here's some additional fruit to save some labor.

Given some additional xml fun:

```
<TopLevel>
    <Inside ident="one">Jibba</Inside>
    <Inside ident="two">Jabba</Inside>
    <Inside ident="one">AlsoJibba</Inside>
    <Inside ident="three">AlsoJabba</Inside>
</TopLevel>
```

I added a where clause that looks for elements inside the parent "TopLevel" that have an ident attribute value of "one".

```
Dim query = From c In loaded.Descendants("TopLevel").Elements("inside")
            Where c.Attribute("ident") = "one"
            Select c.Value
```

Then did a little demo console run of the results:

```
For each inside in query
    Console.WriteLine(inside)
Next
```

Which output:

```
Jibba
AlsoJibba
```

**Spoiler Alert Ahead:**

Now if you copy pasted what I just did and you are using VB like I am you have an especially annoying nuance.  The code doesn't work.  Notice the little section ".Elements("inside") in the LINQ query.  XML is case sensitive.  VB is extremely not case sensitive.  C# users please feel free to ignore our youth. Just wanted to demonstrate a where, and a gotcha.

Matt